# which struts 2 tag need to be used to replace <ilayer> and <layer> tags?

Tags: java, html, struts2

I am new to Struts. I have to migrate code form Struts1 to Struts2 but confused in ilayer tag of Struts1. Please help in writing the equivalent code in Struts2.

```
<ilayer width=&{abc}; height=&{abc}; name="xyz">
   <layer name="xyz"></layer>
   </ilayer>
```

Comment: <ilayer> is a tag from THE NINETIES o_O It has nothing to do with Struts1 nor Struts2, and it is not supported nor needed by any recent browser. Try to understand what id does, and ask a question about how to do it in HTML 5, instead that in HTML 0

Comment: There's no `<ilayer>` tag in Struts. If for no other reason, it's obvious because it doesn't use the tag library prefix--it's just HTML. It is supported by basically no browser except Netscape 4. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_ilayer_tag.htm, http://www.powermapper.com/products/sortsite/rules/bugnonstdilayer/

Comment: thanks for the replys it helped me and can anyone tell how to do it in html5

Comment: and also please can any one tell me the equivalent tag for this <options  collection="abc_TYPE" property="abcid" labelProperty="description"/> options tag in stutrs2

Comment: You need to understand what *each* tag does, and search for something that does the same in the new, right way